# Making resizable char* array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am having an resizable Array implemented in C as follow :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"
void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}
void insertIntoArray(Array *a, int element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = (int *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}
void removeLast(Array *a)
{
    if (a->used == 0) {}
    else{
        a->used--;  
    }   
}
void freeArray(Array *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}
int main(){
    Array a;
    initArray(&a,10);  // initially 10 elements
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        insertIntoArray(&a,i);  
    printf("%d\n",a.array[9]);  
    printf("%d\n", a.used);  
    freeArray(&a);
}
```

Now I need to modify this data structure to store char *’s in the resizeable array instead of integers.So I need to modify the functions for making a set empty, inserting and removing an element into the set, and checking whether an element is in the set. Also set does not include duplicate copies of the same string (char * with the same contents, We can use strcmp to compare strings).

So Please help to modify it.

Example :

```
MySet *s;
initSet(s);
insert(s, “Hello”); 
insert(s, “world”); 
insert(s, “Hello”);
del(s, “world”);
isInSet(s, “Hello”); 
emptySet(s);
```

My ArrayList.h is something like this :

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H
#define ARRAYLIST_H
typedef struct {
  int *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;

void insertIntoArray(Array *a, int element);
void removeLast(Array *a);
void freeArray(Array *a);
void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize);
#endif
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc/realloc in C. Also you should handle errors - malloc and realloc can fail.

Comment: You could use void * so it is generic. This would only work for memory management (malloc, realloc, memcpy, memmove). Then, you would need to create your own specific compare function for each variable type.

Comment: @PaulR Ohk . But how to do the required problem ?

Comment: This is just a comment, not an answer - it's meant to be helpful.

Comment: @PaulR Oh Ohk I will keep this in mind

Comment: Writing type independed code in C isn't trivial. If this really is your use case better go for C++.

Comment: This looks like homework.  People here will not do your homework for you, they will provide help if you cannot succeed after trying.  Change the structure to have a `char **array`  and the `insertIntoArray()` function to take a `const char*`.  First search the string in the array and if not found, duplicate the argument string and store the pointer to the copy into the array the same way you do with `int` currently.  Update the other APIs to free these pointers appropriately.

Comment: @chqrlie Hey please I want to make a library for all datatypes. So was just thinking how to change it. Its not any homework

Comment: The only difference between `int` and a string storage is that you have to store it using `malloc` (use `strdup` if you have it), and use `free` when removing an item.

Comment: @Jongware Can you add some code ?

Comment: You don't understand my suggestion? String handling is a fairly basic part of any C course.

Comment: @Jongware Yeah I do get it. But when I implemented it. I am getting runtime error

Comment: @Jongware What should be structure in ArrayList.h ?

Comment: You cannot make a generic library for all data types in C.  C++ templates would help you do that to some extend.  in C, you should write specific code for different cases.  The structures will have different definitions anyway.  Die hard C aficionados will tell you to use macros to share the code...  Don't follow this advice, this path is paved with landmines and is no longer worth the risk.